# Why is Tverberg's theorem tight?

Tags: convex-analysis, combinatorial-geometry, convex-hulls

How can I find $(r-1)(d+1)$ points in $R^d$ that can't be partioned to $r$ sets who's convex hulls intersect? I would like a proof that is as algebric as possible (meaning rigorous linear algebra etc, and less about geometric facets because they are harder to formalize.)

Thanks.

Comment: Tverberg's original paper explains how to explicitly construct examples establishing the tightness.  His constructions is linear-algebraic, as you desire.

Comment: @Randall Excellent, do you happen to have a link that requires no paywall?

Comment: Hmmm, no, as it appears in the Journal of the LMS which our institution subscribes to.  However (and luckily), the first-page preview contains the construction I've referenced.

https://academic.oup.com/jlms/article-abstract/s1-41/1/123/912427/A-Generalization-of-Radon-s-Theorem?redirectedFrom=fulltext

Comment: Re-reading this, this may not be **exactly** what you need, but it's darn close.

Comment: @Randall haha yeah got lucky there. I think it's the result I want, but I don't really understand it :(